# Recent location & photo album have been removed from my Facebook Wall, and would like them to reappear on Wall in original order

Tags: facebook, profile

I recently updated my location to "Ibiza Spain" but the "location post" (and like/s) have been removed from my Wall (I'm not sure whether I accidentally did so myself). Is there a way for this "location post" (and like/s) to be re-added to my wall, and more importantly, in the order it was originally posted? I.e. I am currently in Barcelona, and would like my Ibiza "location post" to be further down my wall than my Barcelona "location post" (preferably in the order it was originally posted to my Wall). This is important to me for my family and friends to keep up-to-date with my current travels.

I also added a photo album from my time in Ibiza. The photo album (and tags, likes and comments) still exist on my profile under "Photos", but the "Album Post" has been removed from my wall. Is there a way to re-add this "Album Post" (and likes and comments) to my Wall? And as above, in the order it was originally posted?